# Configuring DHCP server (Win 2012)

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell, dhcp

I am trying to do some basic testing of a DHCP server (Windows Server 2012).

I'm trying to do all this testing from a laptop. The VM's are set Host-Only (or 'Private to my Mac' setting)

To get started; I've got **win2012** a DHCP server with a private IP (`172.16.158.128`). This what it defaulted to after setting the host-only networking.

Sample scope set up with basically this:

```
Add-DhcpServerv4Scope -Name "Test Scope" -StartRange 172.16.158.50 -EndRange 172.16.158.60 -SubnetMask 255.255.255.0
```

I am trying to test setting a specific workstation host to always pick up a certain IP.

So I create a Ubuntu VM (again, just something small footprint as my laptop isn't a beast), host only networking. It can ping the `.128` DHCP server.

When I go

`dhclient -v -s 172.16.158.128`

I see `DHCPREQUEST`'s only (or `DHCPDISCOVER`'s)

If I go

`dhclient -v`

I instantly get

```
DHCPREQUEST of 172.16.158.130 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 172.16.158.130 from 172.16.158.254
```

Windows firewall is disabled on **win2012**

What am I missing? How do I get the Windows machine to serve the requests?

---

**edit** The vm's are in VMware Fusion 6.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware Fusion provides its own DHCP-server in the Host-Only network ('private to my mac'). This DHCP-server collides with the Windows Server 2012 DHCP service.

You may whether create a new private network with DHCP and NAT disabled in VMware Fusion -> Preferences -> Network and move both VMs' interfaces to it or disable DHCP in the preconfigured Host-Only network. To disable DHCP in the preconfigured network edit the file /Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/networking and disable DHCP.

Example:

Change

```
VERSION=1,0
answer VNET_1_DHCP yes
answer VNET_1_DHCP_CFG_HASH B77CFE705F74AAb56C1E3CB5E9517746F02E0EC1
answer VNET_1_HOSTONLY_NETMASK 255.255.255.128
answer VNET_1_HOSTONLY_SUBNET 172.16.158.0
answer VNET_1_VIRTUAL_ADAPTER yes
answer VNET_3_HOSTONLY_NETMASK 255.255.255.0
answer VNET_3_HOSTONLY_SUBNET....
```

to

```
VERSION=1,0
answer VNET_1_HOSTONLY_NETMASK 255.255.255.128
answer VNET_1_HOSTONLY_SUBNET 172.16.158.0
answer VNET_1_VIRTUAL_ADAPTER No
answer VNET_3_HOSTONLY_NETMASK 255.255.255.0
answer VNET_3_HOSTONLY_SUBNET....
```

Since method 2 is a default VMware configuration, method 1 (adding a new vmnet) is preferred.

Depending on your (VMware Fusion) network config the IP-address of your Windows Server 2012 and its DHCP range may be wrong additionally.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I saw your earlier comments and started configuring network in fusion but was watching a soccer game and got distracted :) this has resolved the issue. I could do it all through the GUI: create new vmnet, untick provide dhcp server, it gave me a new ip range which I configured on the dhcpserver and all is well! thanks